# What is Global Variable Name in Javascript Variable targeting in Google Optimize?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-optimize

While creating the Targeting Rule Javascript Variable  It asks me to create two variables:

1. Global Variable Name
2. Variable Name

Where we need to define that variable in our code file?
I am having variable `my_variable` in my javascript declared and defined in between `<head>` tag before the google analytics code.

**How I can show the experiment when `my_variable` is having value `10`**? Nothing else I need to match.

**Note:** I need only this Rule to be applied (only One).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Is the current var that are you looking for, for example in the following code is executed just before the Google Optimize's code. (in this case needs to be like this)

```js
<script>
   var "my_var" : 10;
</script>
//optimize Code inserted via Gtag
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-118297712-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'UA-xxxx-1', { 'optimize_id': 'GTM-xxxx'});
</script>
```

In this case is my_var.

Is called gobal because it need that scope to be reachable on the tool, you can look more about the gobal scope in this thread.
[What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript).

Now on the interface i configure it like this (i like to add the type on the var name)
[image]

And now it can be used
[image]

Comment: can you please help me in the way that my variable name is `my_variable` and when it is available in between head tag. I want to implement Google Optimize. just to match the `my_variable` value.
Do you implemented in Google Optimize?